# AngularJS : Should a factory return the definition object or the function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-factory

The official AngularJs developer guide for Directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), in the Creating Directives section, suggests that:

> "**Best Practice: Prefer using the definition object over returning a
>   function.**"

I am not able to connect with this statement. What could be the benefits of doing so? Please could anyone simplify this for me.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. OP asked for `why` not `what`.

Comment: I have edited the question, if that helps. However, its not a opinion-based. It's documented as best practice in official document which is not based upon opinion but some industry rules.